# Changing Accessor type via Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013 and I wanted to create a portion of my project using the class diagramming tool that vs provides me with.

But I ran into one big problem. When I try to change the accessors from read write to read only the area on the property tab of that property is gray and I can only change this directly via code. Am I doing something wrong or is Visual Studio just not capable of performing these changes through the diagram.

Comment: I had to change them in the source file and the class diagram now reads "Read" not "Read/Write".